# Convert a local time with timezone into UTC with ctime

Tags: c++, timezone, ctime

I have been wracking my head crazy trying to figure this out [with this API](http://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/3/ctime/)

My original implementation was something like:

```
// TimezonePtr is just a share_ptr to the timezone 
std::tm getGMT(const std::tm& rawtime, TimezonePtr tz)
{
    std::tm result = rawtime;
    const auto loct = mktime_z(tz.get(), &result);
    gmtime_r(&loct, &result);
    return result;
}
```

However, this does not take into account DST. For example, if I feed it a date of `Sep 28 2012 15:54:24` I get back `Sep 28 2012 20:54:24`, which is incorrect. It looks like I want to use `localtime_rz`, except that takes an epoch, which is driving me nuts because if I could get the epoch then I'd already have my answer. :(

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The STD has a function: tm *gmtime(const time_t *time); Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

`mktime_z` takes a `struct tm` as one of its arguments. If you don't know whether DST is in effect for the input date, you want to set the `tm_isdst` member of that `tm` to `-1` to signify that the system should figure out whether DST is in effect for that date/time/timezone when you call `mktime`.

At least for me, this seems to work correctly (i.e., it correctly concludes that at least in my time zone, DST was in effect in September of 2012).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin)'s correct (and up-voted) answer, I wanted to show how this computation could be done with a [modern C++11/14 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) (free and open source).

I've kept the API the same in the interest of making the code easy to compare:

```
template <class Duration>
auto
getGMT(date::local_time<Duration> rawtime, const date::time_zone* tz)
{
    return tz->to_sys(rawtime);
}
```

This returns a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, Duration>` where `Duration` is the finer of the input `Duration` and `seconds`.  If the `ragtime` doesn't have a unique mapping to UTC according to the indicated time zone, an exception will be thrown.  Such an event can occur (for example) if `rawtime` is during a daylight saving transition and occurs twice, or not at all.  If desired, there exists API for avoiding the exception if you want to "pre-decide" how you would like to map ambiguous and non-existent local times into UTC.

This function can be exercised like this:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << getGMT(local_days{sep/28/2012} + 15h + 54min + 24s,
                        current_zone()) << " UTC\n";
    std::cout << getGMT(local_days{sep/28/2012} + 15h + 54min + 24s,
                        locate_zone("America/New_York")) << " UTC\n";
}
```

This exercises the code twice:

1. With whatever the current time zone is for this computer.
2. With the time zone "America/New_York"

For me these are both the same time zone, resulting in the following output:

```
2012-09-28 19:54:24 UTC
2012-09-28 19:54:24 UTC
```

Not only is it simpler to use this library than the [BSD ctime API](http://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/3/ctime/),
but this API has *type safety*.  For example the UTC time point and local time point are represented by different types, allowing the compiler to tell you if you accidentally use the wrong one.  In contrast the [BSD ctime API](http://www.unix.com/man-page/netbsd/3/ctime/) uses the same type (`tm`) for both local time and UTC.